# send email using library gmailr under batch regime of R

Tags: r, email

I want to send email under batch regime of R (call "D:\R\R-3.2.5\bin\i386\R" --internet2 CMD BATCH script.R). Under gui regime all working very well.

**First edit:**

```
gmail_auth(scope='full',secret_file = 'client_id.json')

notification_email <- mime() %>%
  to("next@gmail.com") %>%
  from("my@gmail.com") %>%
  subject("subject"))
send_message(notification_email)
```

but have

```
Error:oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment.
```

**Second edit**

without gmail_auth

```
notification_email <- mime() %>%
      to("next@gmail.com") %>%
      from("my@gmail.com") %>%
      subject("subject"))
    send_message(notification_email)
```

also have

```
Error: oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with some help from: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/vignettes/managing-auth-tokens.html#where-do-tokens-live-in-between-r-sessions.

Your working directory (`setwd`) needs to be the same in GUI and Rscript.  Before running `gmail_auth`, you must set your working directory to the location of the token. (filename = .httr-oauth).

```
wd <- "C:/My Working Directory/"
setwd(wd)
gmail_auth(scope='full',secret_file = 'client_id.json')
```

1. Add `setwd` command to script
2. Run `gmail_auth` command in GUI
3. Select Option 1 when prompted
4. Save Script
5. Run in Rscript